# Oracle Consistent Gets differ between two servers & performance

Tags: oracle, optimization

So, we have a somewhat complex SQL query.  The performance on our system returns the results in about 1.1 seconds.  On the customers environment, the query returns around 2.4-2.5 seconds. Running statistics on both servers, we noticed a huge difference in consistent gets.  We compared some parameters to see if there's a caching difference, but I'm not entirely sure what to look at.  We did notice the DB_FILE_MULTIBLOCK_READ_COUNT was 8 on their system to our 128.  Basically, looking at the below, is there any direction you could have us go to getting these statistics to match somewhat more closely.

Or, does it not matter that the consistent gets are so different?

```
**Our Statistics**
0 recursive calls
0 db block gets
28344 consistent gets
0 physical reads
188 redo size
1664150 bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
36494 bytes received via SQL*Net from client
3272 SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
1 sorts (memory)
0 sorts (disk)
49053 rows processed

**Client Statistics**
          0  recursive calls
          1  db block gets
     306456  consistent gets
        288  physical reads
        188  redo size
    1879562  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
      36494  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
       3272  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
      49053  rows processed
```

**Our Plan:**

49053 rows selected.

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------                      
Plan hash value: 60030630                                                       

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------                               

| Id  | Operation                              | Name                           
| Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                               

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------                               

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                                
|   454M|   160G|       |   262K  (7)| 00:52:27 |                               

|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                 |                                
|   454M|   160G|       |   262K  (7)| 00:52:27 |                               

|   2 |   VIEW                                 |                                
|     9 |  1935 |       |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |                               

|   3 |    MERGE JOIN                          |                                
|     9 |   198 |       |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |                               

|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | TBLWORKFLOWSTAGES              
|     9 |   144 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|   5 |      INDEX FULL SCAN                   | PK_TBLWORKFLOWSTAGES           
|     9 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|*  6 |     SORT JOIN                          |                                
|     9 |    54 |       |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |                               

|   7 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TBLWORKFLOWSTAGETREE           
|     9 |    54 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|*  8 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                |                                
|   454M|    69G|       |   258K  (6)| 00:51:48 |                               

|   9 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | TBLTASKDEFINITIONS             
|     4 |   148 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|* 10 |    HASH JOIN                           |                                
|   454M|    53G|    22M|   255K  (4)| 00:51:10 |                               

|* 11 |     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN               | IDX_IAM_AS_ID_IN_ID_ACCESS     
|   983K|    11M|       |  1842   (2)| 00:00:23 |                               

|* 12 |     FILTER                             |                                
|       |       |       |            |          |                               

|* 13 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER             |                                
|    39M|  4385M|       |  9180  (71)| 00:01:51 |                               

|  14 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                | TBLASSETSTATUSES               
|     4 |    24 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|* 15 |       HASH JOIN                        |                                
|    79M|  8313M|       |  8614  (69)| 00:01:44 |                               

|* 16 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI            |                                
|  8316 |   446K|       |  2167   (2)| 00:00:27 |                               

|  17 |         INDEX FULL SCAN                | PK_TBLWORKFLOWSTAGETREEPARENTS 
|     7 |    21 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|  18 |         VIEW                           |                                
| 49895 |  2533K|       |  2165   (2)| 00:00:26 |                               

|  19 |          UNION-ALL                     |                                
|       |       |       |            |          |                               

|  20 |           NESTED LOOPS ANTI            |                                
|     1 |   144 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|  21 |            NESTED LOOPS                |                                
|     1 |   106 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|  22 |             INDEX FULL SCAN            | PK_TBLWORKMGMTGP               
|     1 |    13 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|* 23 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TBLASSETTASKS                  
|     1 |    93 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|* 24 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_TBLASSETTASKS               
|     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|* 25 |            INDEX FULL SCAN             | PK_TBLASSETTASKCOPIES          
|     1 |    38 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|  26 |           NESTED LOOPS ANTI            |                                
| 49894 |  6626K|       |  2164   (2)| 00:00:26 |                               

|  27 |            NESTED LOOPS                |                                
| 49894 |  4775K|       |  2163   (2)| 00:00:26 |                               

|* 28 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TBLASSETTASKS                  
|   122K|    10M|       |  2147   (1)| 00:00:26 |                               

|* 29 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_TBLWORKMGMTINST             
|     1 |     5 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|* 30 |            INDEX FULL SCAN             | PK_TBLASSETTASKCOPIES          
|     1 |    38 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                               

|* 31 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TBLASSETS                      
|   827M|    41G|       |   622   (1)| 00:00:08 |                               

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------                               


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                             
---------------------------------------------------                             

   1 - access("QUERYTABLE"."AST_CURRENT_WFST_ID"="DISPLAYTABLE1"."WFST_ID"(+))  
   6 - access("WFST"."WFS_ID"="WFS"."WFS_ID")                                   
       filter("WFST"."WFS_ID"="WFS"."WFS_ID")                                   
   8 - access("DISPLAYTABLE2"."TD_ID"(+)="QUERYTABLE"."TD_ID")                  
  10 - access("TBLASSETS"."AS_ID"="TBLINSPECTORASSETMAP"."AS_ID")               
  11 - filter("TBLINSPECTORASSETMAP"."IN_ID"=1 AND ("TBLINSPECTORASSETMAP"."IAM_
ASSET_ACCESS_LEVEL"=0 OR                                                        

              "TBLINSPECTORASSETMAP"."IAM_ASSET_ACCESS_LEVEL"=1))               
  12 - filter("TBLASSETSTATUSES"."ASSET_STATUS_HIDE_REPORTS" IS NULL OR "TBLASSE
TSTATUSES"."ASSET_STATUS_HIDE_REPORTS"=0)                                       

  13 - access("TBLASSETSTATUSES"."ASSET_STATUS_ID"(+)="TBLASSETS"."ASSET_STATUS_
ID")                                                                            

  15 - access("QUERYTABLE"."AS_ID"="TBLASSETS"."AS_ID")                         
  16 - access("QUERYTABLE"."AST_CURRENT_WFST_ID"="PARENT_WFST_ID")              
  23 - filter("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_TYPE"=3 AND "AST_DELETED"=0)                 
  24 - access("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_ID"="TBLWORKMGMTGP"."AST_ID")                
  25 - access("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_GUID"="COPY_AST_GUID")                       
       filter("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_GUID"="COPY_AST_GUID")                       
  28 - filter("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_TYPE"=4 AND "AST_DELETED"=0)                 
  29 - access("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_ID"="TBLWORKMGMTINST"."AST_ID")              
  30 - access("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_GUID"="COPY_AST_GUID")                       
       filter("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_GUID"="COPY_AST_GUID")                       
  31 - filter("AS_DELETED"=0 AND ("TBLASSETS"."AS_ASSET_DEF"=0 OR "TBLASSETS"."A
S_ASSET_DEF"=1))                                                                


Note                                                                            
-----                                                                           
   - SQL profile "SYS_SQLPROF_014054654a1d0000" used for this statement         


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------                      
          0  recursive calls                                                    
          0  db block gets                                                      
      28343  consistent gets                                                    
          0  physical reads                                                     
          0  redo size                                                          
    1664150  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client                                   
      36494  bytes received via SQL*Net from client                             
       3272  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client                                  
          1  sorts (memory)                                                     
          0  sorts (disk)                                                       
      49053  rows processed
```

**Their Plan:**

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------                      
Plan hash value: 854387336                                                      

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------                                      

| Id  | Operation                               | Name                          
 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                      

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------                                      

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                               
 |     1 |   353 |  1321   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER                     |                               
 |     1 |   353 |  1321   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                    |                               
 |     1 |   149 |  1319   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|*  3 |    FILTER                               |                               
 |       |       |            |          |                                      

|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER                  |                               
 |     1 |   114 |  1318   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                       |                               
 |     1 |   110 |  1317   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                      |                               
 |     1 |   103 |  1317   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS SEMI                |                               
 |     1 |    54 |  1316   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|   8 |         VIEW                            |                               
 | 49426 |  2509K|  1315   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS ANTI              |                               
 | 49426 |  6178K|  1315   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|  10 |           VIEW                          | VW_JF_SET$10554C5A            
 | 49427 |  4344K|  1314   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|  11 |            UNION-ALL                    |                               
 |       |       |            |          |                                      

|  12 |             NESTED LOOPS                |                               
 |       |       |            |          |                                      

|  13 |              NESTED LOOPS               |                               
 |     1 |   106 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|  14 |               INDEX FULL SCAN           | PK_TBLWORKMGMTGP              
 |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|* 15 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_TBLASSETTASKS              
 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|* 16 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TBLASSETTASKS                 
 |     1 |    93 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|  17 |             NESTED LOOPS                |                               
 | 49426 |  4730K|  1313   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|* 18 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TBLASSETTASKS                 
 | 49426 |  4488K|  1310   (1)| 00:00:16 |                                      

|* 19 |               INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TBLINSPECTIONREPORT_IR_TYPE   
 | 49456 |       |   106   (1)| 00:00:02 |                                      

|* 20 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_TBLWORKMGMTINST            
 |     1 |     5 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|* 21 |           INDEX FULL SCAN               | PK_TBLASSETTASKCOPIES         
 |     1 |    38 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|* 22 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                | PK_TBLWORKFLOWSTAGETREEPARENTS
 |     1 |     2 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|* 23 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | TBLASSETS                     
 |     1 |    49 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|* 24 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IDX_ASSET_STATUS_ASID_DELETED 
 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|  25 |       INLIST ITERATOR                   |                               
 |       |       |            |          |                                      

|* 26 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | IDX_IAM_AS_ID_IN_ID_ACCESS    
 |     2 |    14 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|  27 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | TBLASSETSTATUSES              
 |     1 |     4 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|* 28 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | PK_TBLASSETSTATUS             
 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|  29 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | TBLTASKDEFINITIONS            
 |     1 |    35 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|* 30 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | PK_TBLTASKDEFINITIONS         
 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|  31 |   VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                 |                               
 |     1 |   204 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|  32 |    NESTED LOOPS                         |                               
 |     1 |    18 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|  33 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | TBLWORKFLOWSTAGETREE          
 |     1 |     4 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|* 34 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | PK_TBLWORKFLOWSTAGEFLOW       
 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|  35 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | TBLWORKFLOWSTAGES             
 |     9 |   126 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

|* 36 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | PK_TBLWORKFLOWSTAGES          
 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                      

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------                                      


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                             
---------------------------------------------------                             

   3 - filter("TBLASSETSTATUSES"."ASSET_STATUS_HIDE_REPORTS" IS NULL OR         
              "TBLASSETSTATUSES"."ASSET_STATUS_HIDE_REPORTS"=0)                 
  15 - access("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_ID"="TBLWORKMGMTGP"."AST_ID")                
  16 - filter("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_TYPE"=3 AND "AST_DELETED"=0)                 
  18 - filter("AST_DELETED"=0)                                                  
  19 - access("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_TYPE"=4)                                     
  20 - access("TBLASSETTASKS"."AST_ID"="TBLWORKMGMTINST"."AST_ID")              
  21 - access("ITEM_1"="COPY_AST_GUID")                                         
       filter("ITEM_1"="COPY_AST_GUID")                                         
  22 - access("AST_CURRENT_WFST_ID"="PARENT_WFST_ID")                           
  23 - filter("TBLASSETS"."AS_ASSET_DEF"=0 OR "TBLASSETS"."AS_ASSET_DEF"=1)     
  24 - access("AS_ID"="TBLASSETS"."AS_ID" AND "AS_DELETED"=0)                   
  26 - access("TBLASSETS"."AS_ID"="TBLINSPECTORASSETMAP"."AS_ID" AND "TBLINSPECT
ORASSETMAP"."IN_ID"=1 AND                                                       

              ("TBLINSPECTORASSETMAP"."IAM_ASSET_ACCESS_LEVEL"=0 OR "TBLINSPECTO
RASSETMAP"."IAM_ASSET_ACCESS_LEVEL"=1))                                         

  28 - access("TBLASSETSTATUSES"."ASSET_STATUS_ID"(+)="TBLASSETS"."ASSET_STATUS_
ID")                                                                            

  30 - access("DISPLAYTABLE2"."TD_ID"(+)="TD_ID")                               
  34 - access("WFST"."WFST_ID"="AST_CURRENT_WFST_ID")                           
  36 - access("WFST"."WFS_ID"="WFS"."WFS_ID")                                   


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------                      
          0  recursive calls                                                    
          0  db block gets                                                      
     337565  consistent gets                                                    
          0  physical reads                                                     
          0  redo size                                                          
    1728165  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client                                   
      23140  bytes received via SQL*Net from client                             
       3272  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client                                  
          0  sorts (memory)                                                     
          0  sorts (disk)                                                       
      49051  rows processed
```

Comment: First things first.  Are the query plans on the two systems the same?  Do the two systems have exactly the same data (i.e. are you loading an export from their system into your environment or are you running with some test data while the customer is running with live data)?  How different are the data sets?  If you've got 1 million rows of test data but the customer has 20 million rows of live data,  for example, comparing statistics isn't going to be meaningful even if the two queries return the same number of rows in the end.

Comment: Should've mentioned this.  The data is exactly the same.  We did an import of their data a few days ago.   The query plans only differ because there is join optimization done on the customers database, whereas ours does not use that optimization.  Other than the join optimization, the query plans do not differ.  Same indexes, etc.

Comment: What does "join optimization" mean in this context?  If the query plans are different and the customer's site is experiencing slower performance, are you sure that the query plan on the customer site is more efficient than the query plan you have locally?  What happens if you force the two plans to be identical?

Comment: Sorry, meant join factorization.  I turned off join factorization temporarily on the client server and it doesn't use it but the plan is still different.  Ours uses a hash join at a higher level.  Trying to force the hash join on the clients server seems to ignore it.  I've read the pga settings could have an effect here or not.  A side question would be after changing pga setting, do you have to restart the database instance?

Comment: How are you "trying to force the hash join"?  What version of Oracle are you using?  Are you using outlines?  Profiles?  Hints?  Something else?

Comment: When you imported their data did you also import their statistics?  Can you post the two plans, preferably in dbms_xplan.display format?  If the plans are very large, you may want to reduce the problem to the smallest possible query.  (Often times just doing that will help you see what the problem is.)

Comment: We might have imported their statistics but after the import, we rebuilt our indexes and gathered table statistics.  We also did the same on their side also.  I also updated the main post with the two explain plans.   As for the forcing hash join, I used a hint in the select query USE_HASH.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in DB_FILE_MULTIBLOCK_READ_COUNT makes a full table scan probably more efficient on your system than on theirs. On more recent versions you should avoid setting this explicitly as it will default to the maximum possible in that environment. 8 does sound unreasonably low.

An import of the data is not going to be an exact match for the data layout -- you could still have meaningful differences in the data storage, and the only way to exactly guarantee the same layout of data and indexes is through a tablespace transportation.

A low setting for the PGA can conceivably discourage large hash joins as the increased cost of a multipass sort could raise the estimated cost.

So anyway, it does look like your explain plan timing estimations are wildly out. Have you looked at gathering system statistics so the optimiser has a fair estimation of the time required for single block and multiblock reads, and cpu operations?

Comment: I am not familiar with gathering system statistics.  I assume this is different than gathering table statistics?  We can recommend a temporary tweak of DB_FILE_MULTIBLOCK_READ_COUNT as well.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, it profiles system performance: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/stats.htm#i41496

Answer (score 0):

The most significant difference is that your system uses a SQL Profile (as Justin Cave guessed):

```
Note                                                                            
-----                                                                           
   - SQL profile "SYS_SQLPROF_014054654a1d0000" used for this statement
```

Check out [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_sqltun.htm#CHDCJJGF) for information on SQL profiles, such as how to modify them and move them between servers.

Also, [this article by Kerry Osborne](http://kerryosborne.oracle-guy.com/2009/04/oracle-sql-profiles/) can help you see exactly what the profile is doing.

If you want a quick way to force the plans to be the same, run `dbms_xplan` with the option `format => 'outline'`. That will create a large set of hints that will completely control the plan.  You probably do *not* want to permanently use those hints.  But if you can quickly replicate the plan in an ad hoc query you can at least rule out other environment differences.